# Pushing Multiple Repos into Single Repo

Tags: git

I have 5 local repos in a folder that I'm looking to add to a repository I have in VSTS.

I don't mind if the history combines or not, I just need all 5 to appear under the single repo in VSTS.

I create my repo in VSTS and run the following commands.

```
git init
git submodule add "./REPO1"
git submodule add "./REPO2"
git submodule add "./REPO3"
git submodule add "./REPO4"
git submodule add "./REPO5"
git commit -m "Adding Submodules"
git remote add origin "MY-GIT-REPO-URL"
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I thought this would be sufficient but when I clone down from this repo I get the folders but they are empty. Perhaps I should be going about this in another way than Submodules. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is what the .gitmodules file looks like when I clone the repo;

```
[submodule "Repo1"]
    path = Repo1
    url = ./Repo1
[submodule "Repo2"]
    path = Repo2
    url = ./Repo2
[submodule "Repo3"]
    path = Repo3
    url = ./Repo3
[submodule "Repo4"]
    path = Repo4
    url = ./Repo4
[submodule "Repo5"]
    path = Repo5
    url = ./Repo5
```

Comment: A `git subtree` might be what you're looking for. I don't have enough knowledge on it to provide an answer. Check out https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting together the following powershell script that merged everything into a single git. I then `git remote add`ed my VSTS repo and pushed to master. Was delighted to see all my history intact in VSTS!

```
$MyPath = "LocationOfLocalReposToMerge"
$FolderNames = "Repo1","Repo2","Repo3","Repo4","Repo5"
$Processed = @()

git init
dir > deleteme.txt
git add .
git commit -m “Initial dummy commit”

foreach ($element in $FolderNames) 
{
    $name = $element -replace '\s',''
    $Processed += $element

    git remote add -f $name ($MyPath + $element)
    "ADDED REMOTE"
    git merge $name/master --allow-unrelated-histories
    "MERGED"

    if ($element -eq $FolderNames[0]) 
    {
        git rm .\deleteme.txt
        git commit -m “Clean up initial file”
    } 

    mkdir $element
    "DIR CREATED"
    dir –exclude $Processed | %{git mv $_.Name $element}
    "MOVE FILES COMPLETE"
    $CommitMsg = “Move " + $element + " files into subdir”
    git commit -m $CommitMsg
}

"COMPLETE"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep the history, that's more something like that that you want to do:

`git init
git subtree add -P REPO1 ../path/to/REPO1 master
git subtree add -P REPO2 ../path/to/REPO2 master
...`

If you need to keep the history, you should do something similar to:

`git init
git remote add REPO1 ../path/to/REPO1
git remote add REPO2 ../path/to/REPO2
...
git fetch --all
git subtree add -P REPO1 REPO1/master
git subtree add -P REPO2 REPO2/master
...`

Comment: I am hoping to hold onto the history.

Comment: @windowskm Updated with the way to keep history